# Faster way to do a loop with a fair bit of stuff in it

Tags: python

I'm writing a new menu toolkit for pyglet. I have a small snippet that looks (similar) to this:

```
found = False
prevWidget = self.hoverWidget
for widget in reversed(self.widgets):
    newWidget = widget.getChildAtPoint(x, y)
    if newWidget:
        found = True
        self.hoverWidget = newWidget
        if prevWidget != self.hoverWidget:
            if prevWidget:
                prevWidget.doMouseLeave(x, y)
            if self.hoverWidget:
                self.hoverWidget.doMouseEnter(x, y)
        break
if not found and self.hoverWidget:
    self.hoverWidget.doMouseLeave(x, y)
    self.hoverWidget = None
if self.hoverWidget:
    self.hoverWidget.doMouseMove(x, y)
```

It works, but I'm finding it quite unreadable. Some info:

getChildAtPoint() will either return a widget, or None

self.hoveWidget will begin as either a widget, or None

What I'm asking is, is there a nicer way to do this? I'm having a lot of trouble understanding it, and there are a lot of conditions for it to check 60 times a second.

Nice Answer:

```
for widget in reversed(self.widgets):
    newWidget = widget.getChildAtPoint(x, y)
    if newWidget:
        break

if newWidget:
    if self.hoverWidget != newWidget:
        if self.hoverWidget:
            self.hoverWidget.doMouseLeave(x, y)
        self.hoverWidget = newWidget
        if self.hoverWidget:
            self.hoverWidget.doMouseEnter(x, y)
elif self.hoverWidget:
    self.hoverWidget.doMouseLeave(x, y)
    self.hoverWidget = None
if self.hoverWidget:
    self.hoverWidget.doMouseMove(x, y)
```

Comment: This question is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ahhh. I wasn't aware of that site at all. Thanks!

Comment: The last `if` in your original loop is unnecessary, since `self.hoverWiget` has just been set to `newWiget` which was previously tested to be something truthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for widget in reversed(self.widgets):
    newWidget = widget.getChildAtPoint(x, y)
    if newWidget:
        found = True
        self.hoverWidget = newWidget
        if prevWidget != self.hoverWidget:
            if prevWidget:
                prevWidget.doMouseLeave(x, y)
            if self.hoverWidget:
                self.hoverWidget.doMouseEnter(x, y)
        break
```

The `if` body only gets executed once, with the first `newWidget` that isn't `None`. Thus, you can move it out of the loop:

```
for widget in reversed(self.widgets):
    newWidget = widget.getChildAtPoint(x, y)
    if newWidget:
        break
if newWidget:
    # We got a new widget. Do the stuff we want to do with a new widget.
elif self.hoverWidget:
    # We don't have a new widget, but we have an old one.
    # Do the stuff we want to do with the old one.
else:
    # No widgets. Do the stuff for the no widget case.
```